# Poplib issue with LIST/STAT (-ERR Command not understood)

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, poplib

The GMAIL POP3 server does not understand the LIST/STAT command when being sent via poplib. Sending those commands on the same exact mailbox via TELNET works. Initially, I thought this is a GMAIL issue, but after doing the manual TELNET login and message retrieval, it seems something else is going on.

I tried for several days to find a solution via StackOverflow, Google and Discord, but no one could give me an answer.

**FAILED - Poplib outcome with reproducible code:**

[output for the failed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDtKt.png)

```
import poplib
mail_box = poplib.POP3_SSL(SERVER, PORT)
mail_box.set_debuglevel(2)
mail_box.user(USER)
mail_box.pass_(PASSWORD)
mail_box.list()[1]
```

**SUCCESS - Manual TELNET test for the mailbox:**

[output for the successful manual test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Pbj.png)

**Reference to the github issue in cpython:**

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/94019

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I receive an -err command not understood while using the standard poplib library with python. Executing a manual login and list via telnet works fine.